How do I abstract ASP.NET Identity in Clean Architecture so that entities in Domain layer can reference Identity user for relationship mapping
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole, string>, IApplicationDbContext
{

    public DbSet<ChatEntity> Chats { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChatParticipantEntity> ChatParticipants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChatMessageEntity> ChatMessages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
        {
            //Has a list of ChatParticipants 
            //that should have a ApplicationUser as navigation property 
            
        });

 

        builder.Entity<ChatEntity>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasMany(chat => chat.Participants)
                  .WithOne(part => part.Chat)
                  .HasForeignKey(part => part.ChatId)
                  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            entity.HasMany(chat => chat.Messages)
                  .WithOne(message => message.Chat)
                  .HasForeignKey(message => message.ChatId)
                  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });
      
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}


public class ApplicationUserEntity : IdentityUser, IApplicationUser
{
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    public override string Email { get; set; }
    public List<ChatParticipants> ChatParticipations { get; set; }
}

 public class ChatEntity : BaseAuditableEntity
 {
     public List<ChatParticipantEntity> Participants { get; set; }
     public List<ChatMessageEntity> Messages { get; set; }
 }

  public class ChatParticipantEntity : BaseEntity
  {
      public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
      public long ChatId { get; set; }
      public ChatEntity Chat { get; set; }
  }

  public async Task<CommonDataResult<List<Chat>>>Handle
  (GetSignedInUsersChatMessagesQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
      List<string> errors = new List<string>();
      string userId = _currentUserService.UserId;

    //I am trying to get chats that include the participants object that should include     
    //the reference object => applicationUser
      List<Chat> chatEntities = _dbContext.Chats
          .Where(c => c.Participants
          .Any(p => p.ApplicationUserId
          .Equals(userId)))
          .Include(c => c.Participants)
          .Include(c => c.Messages)
          .ProjectTo<Chat>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
          .ToList();
  
      return CommonDataResult<List<Chat>>.Success(chats);
 }




I am using CQRS
The whole point of this approach is so I can meke simple queries using EntityFramwork to get everything I need for a chat.
I welcome any sugggestion to change my approach.
I have tried using an interface to abstract the ApplicationUserEntity but EntityFrameork will not map relationships with an interface.


I keep the the IdentityDbContext separate from the application DbContext where Identity is used solely for authentication/authorization concerns and the application DbContext can have a separate "User" entity defined and mapped to the Users table for app-specific relations. It avoids exposing details the app does not need. Your query is also flawed, ProjectTo is used to project entities to a ViewModel/DTO which should not be instances of the entity classes (Chat) Keep entities concerned with data representation and ViewModels concerned with app domain.

Thank you for the answer @StevePy. I Was kind of hoping this would not be the answer but It seems like it is in fact the only way. Chat is my DTO and ChatEntity is my entity class.
